# How to use a function inside a subroutine in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

Could anyone please tell me why this simple program give me a segmentation fault?

I'm using gfortran, and I need to use a function inside a subroutine.

```
program tst
implicit none

real z,x,y
x=10.
y=2.
call s(10.,10.,z)
print*,z

end program

real function c(x,y)
implicit none
real x, y
c = x*y
return
end

subroutine s(x,y,z)
implicit none
real x, y
real z
real c

z = c(x,y)
end
```

Comment: I tried it, after shifting the code for fixed-form `$ gcc tst.for -o tst -lgfortran && ./tst` comes back with `100.000000`  Fedora 19, AMD

Comment: Seems OK to me, but do note that your subroutines are *not* inside your program, they are *external*, which is the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Better to put your procedures into a module so that their interfaces will be known to each other and any procedure or program `use`ing the module:

```
module MyStuff

contains

function c(x,y)
implicit none
real :: c
real :: x, y
c = x*y
return
end

subroutine s(x,y,z)
implicit none
real :: x, y, z

z = c(x,y)
end

end module MyStuff

program tst
use MyStuff
implicit none

real z,x,y
x=10.
y=2.
call s(10.,10.,z)
print*,z

end program
```

It works, giving answer 100.